# Object filter certain values

Tags: javascript, object

I have this JSON object :

```
{
    "active":     0,
    "0":          "active",
    "inactive":   1,
    "1":          "inactive",
    "ineligable": 2,
    "2":          "ineligable",
    "error":      3,
    "3":          "error",
    "suspended":  4,
    "4":          "suspended",
    "archived":   5,
    "5":          "archived",
    "removed":    6,
    "6":          "removed"
}
```

I want to filter the ones with a numerical value. The thing is I accomplished this already. But in a very ugly way and i wish to know if theres a better way to filter objects than the one I did.

Here's my try :

```
const statuses = listingstatus; //this is the object

let toFill = [];
Object.keys(statuses).forEach(key => {
    if(Number.isInteger(statuses[key])){
        toFill.push({[key]: statuses[key]});
    };

});

console.log(toFill)
```

The result is this :

Array :

```
0: {active: 0}
1: {inactive: 1}
2: {ineligable: 2}
3: {error: 3}
4: {suspended: 4}
5: {archived: 5}
6: {removed: 6}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To still satisfy your requirements you could simplify it by using `Object.entries` instead of `Object.keys` and reduce the result into a single value with `Object.reduce` instead of iterating and pushing onto another variable when necessary

```js
const statuses = {
  "active": 0,
  "0": "active",
  "inactive": 1,
  "1": "inactive",
  "ineligable": 2,
  "2": "ineligable",
  "error": 3,
  "3": "error",
  "suspended": 4,
  "4": "suspended",
  "archived": 5,
  "5": "archived",
  "removed": 6,
  "6": "removed"
}

const toFill = Object.entries(statuses).reduce((all, [key, value]) => Number.isInteger(value) ? [...all, {[key]:value}] : all,[]);

console.log(toFill)
```

However i wonder why do you need such a format in the first place, i think it would be better to just return a single object with those values, instead of an array of object, in which case you would do something like:

```js
const statuses = {
  "active": 0,
  "0": "active",
  "inactive": 1,
  "1": "inactive",
  "ineligable": 2,
  "2": "ineligable",
  "error": 3,
  "3": "error",
  "suspended": 4,
  "4": "suspended",
  "archived": 5,
  "5": "archived",
  "removed": 6,
  "6": "removed"
}

const toFill = Object.entries(statuses).reduce((all, [key, value]) => Number.isInteger(value) ? {...all, [key]:value} : all,{});

console.log(toFill)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've used [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const obj = {
  "active": 0,
  "0": "active",
  "inactive": 1,
  "1": "inactive",
  "ineligable": 2,
  "2": "ineligable",
  "error": 3,
  "3": "error",
  "suspended": 4,
  "4": "suspended",
  "archived": 5,
  "5": "archived",
  "removed": 6,
  "6": "removed"
};

const output = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => Number.isInteger(obj[k]) ? (acc.push({ [k]: obj[k] }), acc) : acc, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
const statuses = listingstatus
Object.keys(statuses).forEach(key => {
    if (isNaN(statuses[key])) delete statuses[key];
});
console.log(statuses)
```

Comment: this mutates the original object which might not be desired